# How do I take an image file and open it on screen?

Tags: java

I'm trying to open a jpg image file from the local directory, and simply draw it to screen.

Here's the code, however the image location isn't referencing and getting all sorts of errors!

Error is: "Cannot find symbol variable g" which is referring to where I have endeavoured to draw the image (see near bottom of code)

I'm a learner - so sorry if its obvious!  Appreciate the help :-)

```
import comp102.*;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.awt.*;


/** A program that plays Rock-Paper-Scissors with the user.
*/
public class RPS{

    String paper = "paper";
    String rock = "rock";
    String scissors = "scissors";    

        /** Play one round of RPS and print out the choices and the result */
    public void playRound(){

        String paper = "paper";
        String rock = "rock";
        String scissors = "scissors";    

        System.out.print ('\f'); // clears screen
        Scanner currentUserSelection = new Scanner(System.in);

        UI.initialise();
        String enterText = null;
        System.out.println("Make your Selection; Paper, Rock or Scissors: ");
        enterText = currentUserSelection.next();

        if(enterText == paper){
        drawImage("paper-left.jpg", 100, 100, null);
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: You have not mentioned the type of variable g. Ex :- Graphics g.. .this is the reason your java compiler is not able to find this g symbol and through this error.

Comment: OK - but it won't work without the g either - so I gather i either haven't imported the correct library and/or I am not leading in with the correct class syntax on the drawImage command?

Comment: I have updated the code... removingt he g - indicating what I am trying to do.  I'll add a method around this later once i have understood the code...

Comment: I recommend looking up `ImageIO`. There are at least three ways to load images in Java, and this is by far the easiest and most robust.

Answer (score 0):

Set the variable with Graphics

```
public void paint(Graphics g){
//image code
}
```